# Ember.js recursive controllers and views

Tags: model-view-controller, recursion, nested, ember.js, ember-router

Say I have a list of `Action` objects, which corresponds to a Ember model. Each has a few properties (timestamps) and a `detail` attribute, which can can recursively contain more `detail`s (arbitrarily deep nesting). You can think of the details as nested lists.

I want to write a UI that allows easy editing (auto completion of values, easy copy and paste, reorder elements, etc) of the `detail` for any `Action` object.

Right now, my `DetailView` template will recursively render additional `DetailView`s:

```
{{#if view.content.hasChildren}}
    {{#each child in view.content.children}}
       {{#DetailView contentBinding=child}}
    {{/each}}
{{#else}}
    {{#EditDetailView contentBinding=view.content.value}}
{{/if}}
```

So each `DetailsView` corresponds to a node in the Details object tree.

But I am unclear how to add controllers to the mix -- there is additional state  I need to store / functionality to implement (e.g., transforming values from the Detail object for display in the DetailsView; handling events for inserting/deleting/reordering elements; changing the structure of the Details tree) that belongs neither in the model nor the view.

Ideally I would have a `DetailsController` serving as a proxy a `Details` per `DetailsView`. **Can I dynamically instantiate controllers and set up their contents within a view template?** My understanding of the new Ember Router is to setup controllers and outlets in in a given route; however, that doesn't seem to apply here because no routing is being done at all. All suggestions / insight about how to handle recursive controllers / views / routes welcome.

I've taken a look at [EmberJS Nested Views and Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602429/emberjs-nested-views-and-controllers), but that proposes I have a single `ArrayController` for all `Detail`s, even across `Action`s ... this would not preserve the tree structure of the nested details either.

I've also looked at [Recursive view in handlebars template not working after upgrading to Ember 0.9.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962647/recursive-view-in-handlebars-template-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ember-0-9-6) but the solution doesn't say anything about controllers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

** UPDATE Feb 20, 2013 **

API documentation for the `{{control}}` helper is now available [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_control). It warns that "The control helper is currently under development and is considered experimental."

To enable it, set `ENV.EXPERIMENTAL_CONTROL_HELPER = true` before requiring Ember.

** UPDATE Feb 3, 2013 **

A new helper `{{control}}` has been added to ember, implementing the *Reusable Views* proposal. So to have a `DetailsController` proxy a `Details` per `DetailsView` you can just:

```
{{control 'detail' child}}
```

See [the {{control}} tests](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/tests/helpers/control_test.js) for example

---

> Ideally I would have a DetailsController serving as a proxy a Details per DetailsView. Can I dynamically instantiate controllers and set up their contents within a view template?

Typically the way to do this would be via the handlebars `{{render}}` helper, which renders a template with an appropriate view and controller. Unfortunately you cannot use `{{render}}` to insert the same template more than once, so it cannot be used within an `{{each}}` block.

There was a lengthy discussion on the topic recently. See: [Non-Singleton Controller Discussion](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1637)!

Two solutions were proposed. The first involves adding an `itemControllerClass` property to ArrayController. If this property was set, the ArrayController would automatically wrap new contents in the specified class. This was added to ember a few weeks ago and takes care of most use cases, where you have a flat-list of items and want each to be wrapped in a proxy.

The second proposal, *Reusable Views*,  allows you to provide a controller class to a view.

```
{{view UI.Calendar dateBinding="post.startDate" controllerClass="App.CalendarController"}}
```

This would create an instance of App.CalendarController for each UI.Calendar widget, which would be tied to the lifecycle of the widget. As of today this has not been implemented. See [{{view}} should have an option to create a controller](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1766)! for the latest status.

So AFAIK there is not a *good* way to accomplish this for the use case you outlined. Meantime, binding data to the view:

```
{{view App.DetailView contentBinding="child"}}
```

and then having some logic in the view itself seems reasonable. If/when Reusable View support is added to master you can pull that logic up into the controller.

See: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1766

Comment: In case anyone is looking for an implementation example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ogapux/9/edit)

Comment: The `control` helper has been depreciated :( I think you're supposed to use `render` now, but I'm getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded " errors.