# Nested Views in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I've got the need for a recursive nested set of views in Ember. Basically think of it as a file structure with folders.

I thought I could do it with `render`, but that didn't work. Inside `structures/show` view:

```
{{#each child in structures}}
  {{ render 'structures/show' child }}
{{/each}}
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: This view is already rendered
```

I read in another [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962647/recursive-view-in-handlebars-template-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ember-0-9-6) about using the `{{view}}` helper:

```
{{#each child in structure.structures}}
  {{ view App.StructuresShowView structureBinding='child'}}<br>
{{/each}}
```

But this doesn't render properly. Possibly because the example is too old?

How do I properly render the same view (and controller?) with a different object in order to build a nested/recursive view? Is there a better way than the object directions?

Thanks.

---

Update. Looks like [itemControllerClass](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1637) might be what I'm looking for? Still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot call `{{render}}` multiple times on a single route. If you need to create something many times, you probably need to use `{{control}}`, which is the same as `{{render}}` with a difference that `{{render}}` has one controller (singelton) and `{{control}}` has a new controller every time it's called.

Here's an [open issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1990) related to your question.

Comment: Thanks twokul. I wish there was an easier way to set this up (or just one that works). I've been trying to do a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ogapux/6/edit) to get _something_ to work, but I've had no success yet.

Comment: I've got a solution with `{{controll}}` working [here](http://jsbin.com/ogapux/9/edit). I do wish there was something nicer.