# When to render via render and when via view?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to figure out when to render a custom view with render and when via view. I know that rendering with render we get the full context (view, controller). But what about view? View is supposed to be for custom views and handing events.

The example below comes form **ember data example**

contacts.hbs

```
<div class="span3">
  <div class="well sidebar-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
      <li class="nav-header">All contacts</li>
      {{#each contact in controller}}
        {{view App.ContactInListView contentBinding="contact"}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="span9">
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

contact_in_list_view.hbs

```
App.ContactInListView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'contact_in_list',
  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: 'isActive:active',

  isActive: function() {
    return this.get('content.id') === this.get('controller.activeContactId');
  }.property('controller.activeContactId')
});
```

contact_in_list.hbs

```
{{#linkTo "contact" contact}}{{contact.fullName}}{{/linkTo}}
```

Couldn't just I render `contact_in_list` with render and pass it some controller?
When should I use render and when view? What's the rule of thumb?

Comment: additional question: the example above uses content binding. Does it mean that both controllers and views have content we can bind to?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with `render`. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971056/nested-views-in-ember/14971239#14971239

Answer (score 2):

> Couldn't just I render contact_in_list with render and pass it some controller?

The `{{render}}` helper can be passed a model but not controller. Probably what you want in this case is the `{{each}}` helper's `itemController` property

```
{{#each contact in controller itemController="contactInList"}}
  {{view App.ContactInListView}}
{{/each}}
```

Have a look at [API docs for Ember Handlebars.helpers](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html)

> When should I use render and when view? What's the rule of thumb?

Use the `{{render}}` helper when you want to render a view/template in the current context using the singleton instance of the same-named controller.

Use the `{{view}}` helper when you want to render a view in the current context without changing to another controller. Like `{{view Ember.TextField}}`